# python2.7 on centos for non root user

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7, centos6

I installed Python2.7.6 on Centos 6.5 using make altinstall. If I do `python2.7 -V` using root, I get the correct answer.

When I use another user that has sudoers permissions I also see everything as normal.

When I switch to another user that does not have sudoers then I get `bash: python2.7: command not found`. When I switch back to root or to my other user (after using the non sudoer user), then suddenly I cannot find Python2.7 there either.

How do I get the python to work?

Comment: "*When I use another user that has sudoers permissions I also see everything as normal.*" - are you running it with sudo? What happens if you try adding and removing sudo permissions on a single account and run the command with and without sudo permissions?

Comment: I am not running python with sudo. Just accessing python is not working (python2.7 -V)

Comment: @Meir if so, then you just have to add `python2.7` to user's `PATH` variable.

Comment: Can you help me out how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated from comments:**

Please add path `python2.7` to path variable `$PATH`, in the user's 
`~/.bashrc or ~/.profile` or

for all  users add it to `/etc/profile`

You can do so by finding line like `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/binary1:/path/to/binary2` 
just add absolute path to `python2.7` after placing a **:** at the end of this line.
and source the file on the terminal you are using `python2.7`.

For subsequent logins it will work, but If you have added in /etc/profile file then you shall have to either source it every time or restart the machine once after making changes to file.

The answer to other part of the question depends on how you are moving back to `root`.

move back to `root` via

```
sudo su -
```

or if you do not need `sudo` then

```
su -
```

[Difference between `su` and `su -`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15611/what-is-the-difference-between-su-and-su-root)

Comment: I need to add my user to group root? The real issue is accessing python2.7 through my new user...

Comment: Have you `make install python2.7` in root home folder ? and binary is somewhere in a root specific path and not normal system path like `/bin/python2.7` or `/usr/bin/python2.7` ???? If yes and you do not want to add user to sudo list then SGID part of the answer holds else it doesn't

Comment: python2.7 is installed in /usr/local. Is that the issue? If it is, how do I change it?

Comment: I guess you dnt have to in this case, have you added python2.7 to user's `PATH` variable?

Comment: I may not have. How do I do that?

Comment: :) then check the user's `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` wherever you find line like `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/binary1:/path/to/binary2` just add absolute path to python2.7 after placing a `:` at the end of this line. more on Google "set PATH variable in Linux" and yes source this file afterward or just open a new terminal

Comment: I have no idea why someone downvoted you. You helped me solve my issue. Please update your answer to include the comments that helped me, and I will mark your answer. Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Someone downvoted because I expected situations and answered everything. My answer was not **specific** to the problem :( . 
I have updated the answer. Now I believe the same person will upvote.

Comment: Anyway, you helped me a lot. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple `PATH` issue.

Modify `/etc/profile` and add something like:

```
export PATH="/path/to/python:$PATH"
```

Normally on many CentOS systems I maintain I install a custom Python
to `` /usr/local/` so my ``PATH`` modification becomes:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

**Note:** This should work in all cases as long as you get the `PATH` right regardless of which user you are logged in with or the use of sudo.